# Using `.map()` inside `thread::scope(...)` and spawning threads inside the closure passed into `thread::scope(...)` doesn't wait for the Futures

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, rust, async-await

Consider the following contrived code snippet, pardon that it is kind of 'long':

```
use anyhow::{Ok, Result};
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread;

// a not-Copy struct
pub struct MoreNumbers {
    third_num: u64,
    fourth_num: u64,
}

pub async fn add_two_num_with_more_number(
    num_one: u64,
    num_two: u64,
    more_nums: &MoreNumbers,
) -> Result<u64> {
    check_num(num_one).await?; // calls another async function that returns a anyhow::Result<T>, where `T` is a different `T` from the return of the `add_two_num` function
    check_num(num_two).await?;
    anyhow::Ok(num_one + num_two + more_nums.third_num + more_nums.fourth_num)
}

pub async fn check_num(num: u64) -> Result<()> {
    assert!(num <= u64::MAX /2, "There is a risk of overflow for adding two u64 numbers that are greater than half of u64::MAX");
    Ok(())
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let mut TRIES: u8 = 5;
    let many_nums: Vec<u64> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
    let more_nums: MoreNumbers = MoreNumbers {
        third_num: 12,
        fourth_num: 13,
    };
    let more_nums_arc: Arc<MoreNumbers> = Arc::new(more_nums);

    while TRIES > 1 {
        many_nums.chunks(2).for_each(|vector| {
            thread::scope(|s| {
                let more_nums_arc_cloned: Arc<MoreNumbers> = Arc::clone(&more_nums_arc);
                if let [first, second] = vector {
                    s.spawn(move || async move {
                        // ------ >>>>> LOOK HERE! <<<<<
                        let result =
                            add_two_num_with_more_number(*first, *second, &more_nums_arc_cloned)
                                .await?;
                        println!("{}", &result); // ------ >>>>> PRINTS TO OUTPUT! <<<<<
                        anyhow::Ok(())
                    });
                };
            })
        });

        TRIES -= 1;
    }
    anyhow::Ok(())
}
```

The above codes compile: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5c3aecb135a1db2c9a80b30e258da0f1).

The `result` is not printed which means that the thread that is spawned in

```
s.spawn(move || async move {
                        // ------ >>>>> LOOK HERE! <<<<<
                        let result =
                            add_two_num_with_more_number(*first, *second, &more_nums_arc_cloned)
                                .await?;
                        println!("{}", &result); // ------ >>>>> PRINTS TO OUTPUT! <<<<<
                        anyhow::Ok(())
                    });
```

is not being awaited on.

Even with `tokio_scoped`, i.e.

```
async fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let mut TRIES: u8 = 5;
    let many_nums: Vec<u64> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
    let more_nums: MoreNumbers = MoreNumbers {
        third_num: 12,
        fourth_num: 13,
    };
    let more_nums_arc: Arc<MoreNumbers> = Arc::new(more_nums);

    while TRIES > 1 {
        tokio_scoped::scope(|s| {
            many_nums.chunks(2).for_each(|vector| {
                let more_nums_arc_cloned: Arc<MoreNumbers> = Arc::clone(&more_nums_arc);
                if let &[first, second] = vector {
                    s.spawn(move |_| async move { // ------ >>>>> LOOK HERE! <<<<<
                        let result =
                            add_two_num_with_more_number(first, second, &more_nums_arc_cloned).await?;
                        println!("{}", &result); // ------ >>>>> PRINTS TO OUTPUT! <<<<<
                        anyhow::Ok(())
                    });
                };
            });
        });
        TRIES -= 1;
    }
    anyhow::Ok(())
}
```

And with taking the `first` and `second` by value, the following error still surfaces. After adding the `()` as what the error has instructed me to do, even more errors surface.

```
error[E0277]: `[closure@src\main.rs:42:29: 42:37]` is not a future
   --> src\main.rs:42:29
    |
42  |                       s.spawn(move |_| async move { // ------ >>>>> LOOK HERE! <<<<<
    |  _______________________-----_^
    | |                       |
    | |                       required by a bound introduced by this call
43  | |                         let result =
44  | |                             add_two_num_with_more_number(*first, *second, &more_nums_arc_cloned).await?;
45  | |                         println!("{}", &result); // ------ >>>>> PRINTS TO OUTPUT! <<<<<
46  | |                         anyhow::Ok(())
47  | |                     });
    | |_____________________^ `[closure@src\main.rs:42:29: 42:37]` is not a future
    |
    = help: the trait `std::future::Future` is not implemented for closure `[closure@src\main.rs:42:29: 42:37]`
    = note: [closure@src\main.rs:42:29: 42:37] must be a future or must implement `IntoFuture` to be awaited
note: required by a bound in `tokio_scoped::Scope::<'a>::spawn`
   --> C:\Users\Jym Chng.DESKTOP-N84UN90\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-scoped-0.2.0\src\lib.rs:175:12
    |
175 |         F: Future<Output = ()> + Send + 'a,
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `tokio_scoped::Scope::<'a>::spawn`
help: use parentheses to call this closure
    |
47  |                     }());
    |                      ++
```

Error after adding the `()`:

```
error[E0618]: expected function, found `impl std::future::Future<Output = std::result::Result<(), anyhow::Error>>`
  --> src\main.rs:42:38
   |
42 |                        s.spawn(move |_| async move { // ------ >>>>> LOOK HERE! <<<<<
   |   ______________________________________^
   |  |______________________________________|
   | ||
43 | ||                         let result =
44 | ||                             add_two_num_with_more_number(first, second, &more_nums_arc_cloned).await?;
45 | ||                         println!("{}", &result); // ------ >>>>> PRINTS TO OUTPUT! <<<<<
46 | ||                         anyhow::Ok(())
47 | ||                     }());
   | ||_____________________^-- call expression requires function
   | |                      ||
   | |______________________|help: consider using a semicolon here: `;`
```

My question is:
How can I make it be awaited on?

Comment: You can use `await` to wait for the competion of a future, where do you do that? Threads are orthogonal to asynchronous code.

Comment: Also refer to my comment on your last question please provide a [***minimal*** reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of dumping your whole code here!

Comment: `tokio_scoped::Scope::spawn` takes a future, not a closure, drop the `move ||`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code shows a misunderstanding of how threads, `thread::scope`, and async works, so lets fix that.

To start with, I'm removing all async/tokio stuff. I'll add it back later. I'm also removing `anyhow` just for simplicity.

## Scope

Right now, you have something like this:

```rs
thread::scope(|s| {
    s.spawn(do_stuff)
})
```

This is nearly useless. Semantically, it's the same as this:

```rs
do_stuff()
```

`thread::scope` joins all spawned threads at the end of its scope, but since you only spawn one thread and it's spawned at the end of the scope, the scope immediately joins the thread and nothing is done in parallel.

In general, you should make your `thread::scope` as large as possible. I'm not sure what you intend with the while loop, so I've settled on this: [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d2d43297bc43e2b47336da39034992f0)

```rs
while tries > 1 {
    thread::scope(|s| {
        many_nums.chunks(2).for_each(|vector| {
            if let &[first, second] = vector {
                let more_nums = &more_nums;
                s.spawn(move || {
                    let result = add_two_num_with_more_number(first, second, more_nums)?;
                    println!("{}", &result);
                    Result::Ok(())
                });
            };
        });
    });

    tries -= 1;
}
```

This goes through all the chunks of `many_nums` in parallel, waits for all those to finish, then does that again 3 more times.

## Arc

I've completely removed `more_nums_arc` and its clones. Using `thread::scope` is usually a replacement for using `Arc`, since it removes the need for shared state to live for `'static`. You can use a regular reference, which I've created with the line `let more_nums = &more_nums;`. This needs to be done before the closure since `first` and `second` need to be moved, but not the original `more_nums`.

## Async

When using async, for each future you create, you need to either await it, or run it on an executor. When you create a future with an `async {}` block, you need to await it in order to run it. You code never does that. `Scope::spawn` does not run or await it, either.

To fix this, we can give each thread its own executor. I've brought back the async `add_two_num_with_more_number`, but not `tokio::main`. [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=77cb7bc9e0c88ee74ad9f2c5253fe924)

```rs
s.spawn(move || {
    let block = async {
        let result =
            add_two_num_with_more_number(first, second, more_nums).await?;
        println!("{}", &result); // ------ >>>>> PRINTS TO OUTPUT! <<<<<
        Result::Ok(())
    };
    tokio::runtime::Builder::new_current_thread()
        .build()
        .unwrap()
        .block_on(block)
});
```

## Tokio

This works, but it is very unusual to use `std::thread` and `tokio` at the same time. Just like `Arc` and `thread::scope`, they solve the same problems, so using both is redundant. Lets bring back `tokio::main`.

You've found `tokio-scoped`, but its Github readme says to use [`async-scoped`](https://docs.rs/async-scoped/), so I'll use that. You nearly found the answer, but you need to pass the async block directly instead of passing a closure. [(playground but doesn't compile because of dependencies)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d749dc8f9bea68da3f5e86e1b7f83a41)

```rs
async_scoped::TokioScope::scope_and_block(|s| {
    many_nums.chunks(2).for_each(|vector| {
        if let &[first, second] = vector {
            let more_nums = &more_nums;
            s.spawn(async move {
                let result = add_two_num_with_more_number(first, second, more_nums).await?;
                println!("{}", &result);
                Result::Ok(())
            });
        };
    });
});
```

I hope this clears up some of the confusion.

Comment: Thank you @drewtato for taking your time to write this terrific explanation for everyone on StackOverflow! Personally, I am grateful!